# Is working online from home haram?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I am working in an online company. I know there is a cost price and a sale price so in this way the work is not haram. But second question is that I am working by sitting at home. I don't say I don't work totally. I manage customers and deal with the delivery man, but I'm still confused as to whether it is halal or haram?

Comment: The question didn't say anything about "riba", yet it was tagged "riba".  I removed this tag, but please explain how it's relevant (if it is).

Answer (score 1):

Working from Home is not haram. Allah ask us to find job which do not spoil salah ( Namaz) . And prophet Mohammed prohibited several types of jobs like cheating, gambling , anything relate with loan interest kind of . If you are working from home means your management trusting you. You will be in your work. So simply fear allah.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: Jazakallah kair. Will see and will modify my answer